# Can I style text within a JS object?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styling

For example I have this object:

```
function getBadgeContent() {
    let os = detectOS();
    let obj = {};

    if( os == "android" ) {
        obj = {
            src: "----",
            href: "---",
            info: "Download app for Android"
        };
    } else if( os == "iOS" ) {
        obj = {
            src: "---",
            href: "---",
            info: "Download App for iOS"
        };
    } else {
        obj = {
            src: "---",
            href: "----",
            info: "Download App for Windows"
        };
    return obj;

}

    }
```

This object is then called (not sure if this is the correct term). And a different badge is displayed in an HTML page depending on the device the user is on.

```
function buildBadge() {
    let obj = getBadgeContent();
    let html = '';

    if( obj ) {
        html = obj.info + '<a target="_blank" href="'+ obj.href+'"><img src="' + obj.src + '" alt="store_badge" /></a>';
    }

    return html;

}
```

I want to give **info** specific styling. Basically I want the text to display above the badge and say "Download for your specific device".

As a bonus, I would like to give each badge styling rules so that they are all the same height and width. But that can be done outside of code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add styling to the 'a'(anchor) element with a style attribute
`<a style="height: 100px"></a>` for example and just add the css that goes in the style attribute as a new property to your json object.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably shorten your functions quite a bit by cutting out the repetitions.

And, as you can see in my little demo, do all the formatting in CSS.

```js
function addBadge(ev){
 let OO={android:['androidforums','href4android.html','android'],
     iOS:['apple','iOS_href.html','iOS'],
     win10:['microsoft','win10_href.html','windows']};
 var o=OO[detectOS()]||OO.win10;
 document.getElementById('main').innerHTML+='<div class="badge">Download app for '+o[2]
   +'<br><a href="'+o[1]+'"><img src="//logo.clearbit.com/'+o[0]+'.com"></a></div>';
}
var i=0;
function detectOS(){ // dummy function
  return ['android','iOS'][i++%3];    
}

document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click',addBadge)
```

```css
.badge {display:inline-block; height:80px;width:200px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    text-align:center; margin:6px}
.badge img {height:32px;}
```

```html
<button id="add">add</button>
<div id="main"></div>
```